# Restart disabled due to context in which it is running

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

failed to run test class,when I run,it showed this error message:

```
14:12:02.493 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener -- Restart disabled due to context in which it is running

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.2)


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal problem occurred, please report it. Mockito is unable to load the default implementation of class that is a part of Mockito distribution. Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
    at 
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.

It appears as if your JDK does not supply a working agent attachment mechanism.
Java               : 21
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 21.0.2+13-58
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 21.0.2+13-58
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Windows 11
OS version         : 10.0

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
    
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal problem occurred, please report it. Mockito is unable to load the default implementation of class that is a part of Mockito distribution. Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.

It appears as if your JDK does not supply a working agent attachment mechanism.
Java               : 21
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 21.0.2+13-58
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 21.0.2+13-58
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Windows 11
OS version         : 10.0


Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal problem occurred, please report it. Mockito is unable to load the default implementation of class that is a part of Mockito distribution. Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker]

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I specified the class name in @SpringBootTest():

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Demo1Application.class)
class Demo1ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }

}
```

but got this:

```
14:14:28.035 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener -- Restart disabled due to context in which it is running

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.2)

2024-02-17T14:14:28.390+08:00  INFO 19588 --- [           main] com.example.Demo1ApplicationTests        : Starting Demo1ApplicationTests using Java 21.0.2 with PID 19588 (started by 凛 in C:\Users\凛\Desktop\Java\demo1)
2024-02-17T14:14:28.391+08:00  INFO 19588 --- [           main] com.example.Demo1ApplicationTests        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-02-17T14:14:28.997+08:00  WARN 19588 --- [           main] o.m.s.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner      : No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.example]' package. Please check your configuration.
2024-02-17T14:14:29.180+08:00 ERROR 19588 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : An incompatible version [1.2.31] of the Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version [1.2.34]
2024-02-17T14:14:29.719+08:00  INFO 19588 --- [           main] com.example.Demo1ApplicationTests        : Started Demo1ApplicationTests in 1.692 seconds (process running for 2.581)
WARNING: A Java agent has been loaded dynamically (C:\Users\ÁÝ\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.14.11\byte-buddy-agent-1.14.11.jar)
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is in use, please run with -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading to hide this warning
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is not in use, please run with -Djdk.instrument.traceUsage for more information
WARNING: Dynamic loading of agents will be disallowed by default in a future release
2024-02-17T14:14:30.239+08:00  WARN 19588 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while invoking 'beforeTestMethod' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener] for test method [void com.example.Demo1ApplicationTests.contextLoads()] and test instance [com.example.Demo1ApplicationTests@2b79c8ff]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.



2024-02-17T14:14:30.248+08:00  WARN 19588 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while invoking 'afterTestMethod' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener] for test method [void com.example.Demo1ApplicationTests.contextLoads()] and test instance [com.example.Demo1ApplicationTests@2b79c8ff]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)


    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:260) ~[mockito-core-5.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:23) ~[mockito-core-5.7.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.appendToClassLoaderSearch0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch(InstrumentationImpl.java:280) ~[na:na]
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.<clinit>(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:177) ~[mockito-core-5.7.0.jar:na]
    ... 72 common frames omitted


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:84)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy70.getHandler(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.getMockHandlerOrNull(MockUtil.java:158)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.isMock(MockUtil.java:147)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.DefaultMockingDetails.isMock(DefaultMockingDetails.java:32)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:320)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeEach(SpringExtension.java:240)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:84)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy70.getHandler(Unknown Source)
        at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.getMockHandlerOrNull(MockUtil.java:158)
        at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.isMock(MockUtil.java:147)
        at org.mockito.internal.util.DefaultMockingDetails.isMock(DefaultMockingDetails.java:32)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:106)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:73)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:67)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:487)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterEach(SpringExtension.java:278)
        ... 2 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal problem occurred, please report it. Mockito is unable to load the default implementation of class that is a part of Mockito distribution. Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.DefaultMockitoPlugins.create(DefaultMockitoPlugins.java:105)
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.DefaultMockitoPlugins.getDefaultPlugin(DefaultMockitoPlugins.java:79)
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:75)
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:50)
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:27)
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:22)
        at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<clinit>(MockitoCore.java:73)
        at org.mockito.Mockito.<clinit>(Mockito.java:1683)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:105)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:73)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:320)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeEach(SpringExtension.java:240)
        ... 2 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.DefaultMockitoPlugins.create(DefaultMockitoPlugins.java:103)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.

It appears as if your JDK does not supply a working agent attachment mechanism.
Java               : 21
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 21.0.2+13-58
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 21.0.2+13-58
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Windows 11
OS version         : 10.0

        at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:260)
        at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:23)
        ... 18 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.appendToClassLoaderSearch0(Native Method)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch(InstrumentationImpl.java:280)
        at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.<clinit>(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:177)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal problem occurred, please report it. Mockito is unable to load the default implementation of class that is a part of Mockito distribution. Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker]


Process finished with exit code -1
```

finally I tried this annotation --> @ContextConfiguration(classes = Demo1Application.class) ：

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Demo1Application.class)
class Demo1ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }

}
```

it worked.so why the default code provided spring boot3 cannot be run ? I don't want to do like that way,could anyone help me run with the default code?
[it worked,but I want to use the default code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtbCs.png)